# What cause protobufs to create tousands of methods when compiled into Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

When you compile a protobuf (proto) files into Java it created around 450 method in java. (this is my own case). Thats what a simple method counter gives me as the number. But when java started compiling it turned in to range of 10,000.

What cause this behaviour?. I assume its related to how java compiles classes and sub classes.

Comment: How did you measure this number?

Comment: as a one thing i get "Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" as the error when i try to compile my project into android.

Comment: Consider using one of the alternative Protobuf Java implementations optimized for Android, e.g. [Square's Wire](https://github.com/square/wire).

Answer (score 0):

The [protobuf java documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated) lists all of the Java code that will be generated for a protobuf.

450 methods does seem like a high number, obviously it will depend on the structure of your protobuf file - do you have a particularly large number of messages / fields ?